mac postgress - Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
I was trying to install and run postgres 16 on mac and I got this error
dyld[30279]: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: <4A4C9EBE-1868-317F-A86C-2DAE62CA9064> /usr/local/bin/psql
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libpq.5.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
[1]    30279 abort      psql


This is what I did before I got the error
brew install postgresql@16
brew services start postgresql@16
brew services list
psql


I'm just too lazy and installed postgres.app years ago and never looked back: https://postgresapp.com

I solved this
I just do this rm -rf /usr/local/bin/psql
And remove all postgres that were installed by homebrew
Then install postgres app from https://postgresapp.com/downloads.html
Now my psql commpand works

